# Copy difference between source and destination folders to a third folder

Tags: file, directory, robocopy, delta

How can I use robocopy to copy only the difference between 2 folders to a third folder (and not the destination folder)?

So if "SourceFolder" contains FileA , FileB , FileC and "DestinationFolder" contains FileA and FileB , I would like to see "DifferencesFolder" containing FileC.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a batch file with [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) comparing the files, creating a list and then looping the list and copying files.

Comment: At this point of time, I would like to only use Robocopy. It is not a real constraint, but my deployment team is familiar with Robocopy.

Comment: Sorry, I use Robocopy a bit but would not sure if it can do this.  I would have just used a batch file for quickness.